# Editing Oracle Spatial view from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, oracle-spatial

I try with QGIS to insert new features in a multi-table Oracle Spatial view that is updatable by adding an "instead of" trigger. The view is "key-preserved" and I don't have any problem when I insert a new feature directly in SQL.

But when I try to do this in QGIS (QGIS 2.18.24 as QGIS 3.2) I get this error :

```
Oracle error while adding features: Oracle error: Could not retrieve feature id -2
SQL: Error: SELECT "OBJECTID" FROM "MY_SCHEMA"."MY_VIEW" WHERE ROWID=:f
```

Despite this error, the feature is inserted in my database anyway. The problem is, if I save layer edits another time, my feature would be recorded 2 times.

Is this a limitation of the Oracle Spatial QGIS connector or I can do something to have a workaround solution?

Comment: I have never had an issue with Oracle Spatial Editing in QGIS - is there any restrictions on the user? like update/commit?

Comment: There is no restriction on the user who is the tables and view owner. I don't have any problems with Oracle Spatial tables either, only with Oracle Spatial views. I think the problem is there are no ROWID pseudocolumn in oracle views while there are in tables

Comment: is it the same issues as this https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19259 ?

Comment: No, I think this issue is due to the date format only in QGIS 3.x

Comment: A new small precision : this issue occurs only with multi-table view. With a view that is a mirror of an unique table there is no problem.